# Best portable device for getting spectral data?

Tags: portable

I'd like to capture some samples of reflectance spectra from the real world.

So perhaps I'm looking for some kind of spectrometer, or spectrophotometer, for wavelengths of visible light, with an LED display which can operate standalone and which can save and export the spectral data to a computer.

(Examples of said type:
[1](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005002149283898.html)
[2](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005005363517720.html))

Or perhaps I'm looking for some kind of Bluetooth peripheral where a smartphone becomes the display.

(Example of said type:
[1](https://www.amazon.com.au/dp/B07ND647G6/))

The main thing is the ability to actually get the data out.

I've been going through the listings for many such devices but nobody is super descriptive about how the data is handled.